# How to exclude a range of values in an interval

Tags: plotting

i'm trying to draw an irrotational vortex with this function:

```
ListVectorPlot[Table[{-y/(x^2 + y^2), x/(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -3, 3, 3}, {y, -3, 3, 3}]]
```

But as you can see this function has a singularity in the origin, so how can i exclude a certain range of values close to the origin?

Thanks?

Comment: Could use `If[]` in `Table[]` to eliminate the singular points at the outset.

Comment: Thanks but how? If[x==y==0, ?, ?]

Comment: Yes, like that. `Table[If[x == y == 0, {0, 0}, (* stuff *)], (* stuff *)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit hacky, but you can do this:

```
Quiet[
 ListVectorPlot[
  Table[
   {-y/(x^2 + y^2), x/(x^2 + y^2)}, 
   {x, -3, 3, 1}, {y, -3, 3, 1}
   ] /. Indeterminate -> 0
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ListVectorPlot[
Table[{y/(x^2+y^2+2),-x/(x^2+y^2+2)},{x,-3,3,0.3},{y,-3,3,0.3}],PlotTheme -> "Minimal"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-specify the points you wish to plot. Here's one way of doing so using `CirclePoints`, which allows you to easily specify a minimum radius:

```
With[{pts =
   Flatten[Table[CirclePoints[n/2, 4*n + 1], {n, 1, 6}], 1]},
 ListVectorPlot[
  N@Map[Replace[p : {x_, y_} :> {p, {-y, x}/(x^2 + y^2)}], pts]]]
```

[image: vector plot]